# Why is my JavaScript for suspending and unsuspending a user not working correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm building a site for someone and on the Admin side there is a "Manage Users" page to manage the website's users. Here is my two functions to suspend and unsuspend (and for the alert):

```
var admin = {
    alert: (function(msg,dur) {
        if(!dur || dur == null) {
            dur = 1500;
        }
        $('#alert_box2').remove();
        $('body').append('<div id="alert_box2" style="width: 100%; height: 9px; top: -17px; left: 0; position: absolute; text-align: center; z-index: 5;"><div id="alert_box_inner2"></div></div>');
        $('#alert_box2').show(0, function() {
            if(dur!=='none') {
                $('#alert_box_inner2').html(msg).stop(true, true).fadeIn(800).delay(dur).fadeOut(800, function() {
                    $('#alert_box2').remove();
                });
            }
            else {
                $('#alert_box_inner').html(msg).show();
            }
        });
    }),
    suspendUser: (function(id) {
        admin.alert('Please wait...',20000);
        $.get('user_more_actions.php?action=suspend&nolightbox=1&id='+id, function(data,textStatus) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(textStatus=='success') {
                    if(data.indexOf('suspended') > -1) {
                        name = data.replace('suspended ','');
                        admin.alert(name+' is now suspended.',2500);
                        $('#status_'+id).html('<strong style="color: red;">Suspended</strong>');
                        $('#suspend_'+id).attr('id','unsuspend_'+id).text('Unsuspend').removeClass('suspend').addClass('unsuspend');
                    }
                    else {
                        admin.alert('Sorry, there was an error. <span class="s_link" onclick="$(\'#suspend_'+id+'\').click();">Try again</a>','none');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    admin.alert('Sorry, there was an error. <span class="s_link" onclick="$(\'#suspend_'+id+'\').click();">Try again</a>','none');
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    }),
    unsuspendUser: (function(id) {
        admin.alert('Please wait...',20000);
        $.get('user_more_actions.php?action=unsuspend&nolightbox=1&id='+id, function(data,textStatus) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(textStatus=='success') {
                    if(data.indexOf('unsuspended') > -1) {
                        name = data.replace('unsuspended ','');
                        admin.alert(name+' is no longer suspended.',2500);
                        $('#status_'+id).html('<strong style="color: green;">Active</strong>');
                        $('#unsuspend_'+id).attr('id','suspend_'+id).text('Suspend').removeClass('unsuspend').addClass('suspend');
                    }
                    else {
                        admin.alert('Sorry, there was an error. <span class="s_link" onclick="$(\'#unsuspend_'+id+'\').click();">Try again</a>',20000);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    admin.alert('Sorry, there was an error. <span class="s_link" onclick="$(\'#unsuspend_'+id+'\').click();">Try again</a>',20000);
                }
            }, 500);
        });
    })
};
```

And the code that triggers the functions when a Suspend or Unsuspend link is clicked:

```
$('.suspend').each(function() {
    $(this).live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('suspend_', '');
        admin.suspendUser(id);
    });
});
$('.unsuspend').each(function() {
    $(this).live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('unsuspend_', '');
        admin.unsuspendUser(id);
    });
});
```

Everything is working ok, except when I click again it messes up. When a Suspend link is clicked, it changes to Unsuspend (and changes the ID). But then if I click Unsuspend it doesn't work, and it is calling the `admin.suspend()` function instead of `admin.unsuspend()` (and the ID isn't being passed so the name isn't displayed):

[image: screenshot]

When the class and the ID is changed it should call either the `admin.suspend(id_here)` or `admin.unsuspend(id_here);` but it isn't.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thanks in advance and I'm sorry that this post is long.

Comment: Not concerned about the length, but I'll accept an apology for the complete lack of indentation :p

Comment: If you remove a class from an element with a `live` on that class, does it remove the handler as well? What happens if you reverse the suspend/unsuspect class loops, is the behavior reversed?

Comment: @DaveNewton No, I don't think so, but I tried just using `.click()` and it didn't work so I changed to `.live('click')` and it still didn't work. I thought `live` would work because it is dynamically adding/removing classes but obviously it doesn't.

Comment: @rcdmk No I don't need `live` I was just trying that but it didn't work. I'm linked to `/jquery-latest.js` so I have the newest version. I did have `click` initially but it didn't work. I'll try `on`.

Comment: Try to use another attribute instead of the id. Something like `data-mode="suspend"` (`data` attributes can have any name you want after the `data-` part and store any value)

Comment: @rcdmk oh, cool. I'll try that also.

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone, @Kevin's answer helped the best and I used `rel` instead of changing the ID and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fiddled with it. Hope this helps:http://jsfiddle.net/wKGKu/

Update: After reading your concerns for .each, I've updated the code to demonstrate it isn't needed: http://jsfiddle.net/wKGKu/2/

Answer (score 1):

You are attaching events to suspend/unsuspend **classes**, but your AJAX callback is modifying  **id** attribute. Also you are horribly misusing `live()`. In the end your handler is already attached to the link and doesn't change after your AJAX calls.

Solution is to

1) leave ID's alone - you are only confusing yourself by modifying them
2) rewrite event handler to either not do `each()` or not use `live` - put together completely defeats purpose behind `live()`

```
$('.suspend').live('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('suspend_', '');
    admin.suspendUser(id);
    return false;
});
$('.unsuspend').live('click', function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('suspend_', '');
    admin.unsuspendUser(id);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Actually it is modifying the class as well: `$('#suspend_'+id).attr('id','unsuspend_'+id).text('Unsuspend').removeClass('suspend').addClass('unsuspend');` I only used `live` to test to see if that would work (if you read the comments).

Comment: The point is you need to stick to single criteria. Either use ID or class. But changing element ID is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: How is changing ID a bad idea? I've done it in past web applications that I've made and it works fine. It doesn't confuse me.

Comment: @Nathan I'd consider an id a constant, absolute thing--and there's no reason to change it. My SSN doesn't change, nor do IDs of DB entities, why should the DOM be treated any differently?

Comment: @DaveNewton I'll just use `rel` to reference to it then. Like: `$('a[rel='+id+']').text('Suspend').removeClass('unsuspend').addClass('suspend');`. That'd work, right?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the way you wrote your live bindings is incorrect, they should have been bound like this:

```
$('.suspend').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('suspend_', '');
    admin.suspendUser(id);
});

$('.unsuspend').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('id').replace('unsuspend_', '');
    admin.unsuspendUser(id);
});
```

I simplified fiddle showing the working code at: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luisperezphd/fvnTq/)